# didn't get current location

Tags: google-maps, flutter

[image]

I trying to get current location by geolocator package by this code below

```
 GoogleMapController mapController;
  Position _currentPosition;
  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(30.033333, 31.233334), // egypt
    zoom: 5.4746,
  );
```

and this is the button function which should go to the current location

```
onTap: () {
                          mapController.animateCamera(
                            CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                              CameraPosition(
                                target: LatLng(
                                  _currentPosition.latitude,
                                  _currentPosition.longitude,
                                ),
                                zoom: 18.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
```

Comment: Please provide the code how do You get the _currentPosition variable, I guess you don't assign it anywhere

Comment: i tried the answer below
but it gives me a wrong location to me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the [ReadMe](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) on Geolocator I would probable do it like this. I haven't tested it myself.

```
onTap: () async {
_currentPosition = await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
                      mapController.animateCamera(
                        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                          CameraPosition(
                            target: LatLng(
                              _currentPosition.latitude,
                              _currentPosition.longitude,
                            ),
                            zoom: 18.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
```

To me it looks like you did not assign any values to _currentPosition, just said it was of the type Position, therefore you get a null result

Comment: it gives me a wrong location to me!!

Comment: If you are running an emulator then it will not give you your location, but the emulator location which is typically Googleplex on Android if you haven't changed the emulator location.

Comment: I changed Googleplex(initial camera position) to be Egypt so when I click in my location button , goes to different place “America”